# Can not get item from List in java

Tags: java, applet, awt

So I m making an applet and it has to get the item and say at what age is the person in something like alert window . I get error for trying to get an selected item by the index in the list . I was reviewing some of the topics in stackoverflow , but I was finding only getting item from ArrayList and I m using List(I think there is difference) and find that getSelectedIndex(index) from a site for applets . But I have no clue why it gives me the error on that line : 
The method getSelectedIndex() in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (int).
I just need to get that selected index and that way I ll get the item and when I know it is selected I ll run my logic . Sorry I m not that good in java .
Here is the code:

```
package course;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.*;//vnimavai kak go pishesh
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class applet extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    int fontStyle = Font.PLAIN;
    TextField name_enter;
    TextField pass_enter;
    TextField pass_re;
    List age;
    CheckboxGroup radioGroup;
    Checkbox radio1;
    Checkbox radio2;
    Button send;
    Button clear;

    public void init()
    {
        radioGroup = new CheckboxGroup();
        radio1 = new Checkbox("male",radioGroup,true);
        radio2 = new Checkbox("female",radioGroup,false);
        send = new Button("send");
        clear = new Button("clear");
        name_enter = new TextField("",20);
        pass_enter = new TextField("",14);
        pass_re = new TextField("",14);
        age = new List();
        name_enter.setBounds(100, 100, 130, 70);
        pass_enter.setBounds(100, 110, 130, 80);
        pass_re.setBounds(100, 120, 130, 70);
        age.setBounds(100, 130, 130, 70);
        radio1.setBounds(100, 140, 130, 70);
        radio2.setBounds(100, 150, 130, 70);
        send.setBounds(100, 160, 130, 70);
        clear.setBounds(105, 160, 130, 70);
        add(new Label("Enter name:"));
        add(name_enter);
        add(new Label("Enter password >=6 char:"));
        add(pass_enter);
        add(new Label("Reenter password:"));
        add(pass_re);
        add(new Label("Enter age:"));
        add(age);
        age.add("-30");
        age.add("31-50");
        age.add("51+");
        add(new Label("You are:"));
        add(radio1);
        add(radio2);
        add(send);
        add(clear);
        send.addActionListener(this);
        clear.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evnt)
    {
        if(evnt.getSource()==send)
        {
            if(age.getSelectedIndex(0))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Send button pushed.");
            }
            else if()
            {

            }
            else if()
            {

            }
                repaint();
        }
        else if(evnt.getSource()==clear)
        {
            name_enter.setText(null);
            pass_enter.setText(null);
            pass_re.setText(null);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @alejandrogiron how can you new an interface like that?

Comment: @Ivan Petrov "getting item from ArrayList and I m using List(I think there is difference)" -> `ArrayList` is a class implementation for `List`

Comment: @alejandrogiron did you see anyone `new List<String>()` like you do?

Comment: @alejandrogiron Hello and thank for the answer in order to do what you are saying I have to change import java.awt.List; to import java.util.List; , but with that change I get errors at .setBounds() and making List<String> gives e the error:The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). 3) Why use AWT?   ..

Comment: .. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The java.awt.List has no parameters in getSelectedIndex();

Please refer to documentation for full information: [Reference Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html)

2) You are trying to pass the function with return type `int` to `if( )` block which works only with boolean values.

So, this part shoud look like this:

```
if (age.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Send button pushed.");
}
```

Or:

```
if (age.isIndexSelected(0)) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Send button pushed.");
}
```

> isIndexSelected(int index)
>   - Determines if the specified item in this scrolling list is selected

.

Comment: Thank you so much <3 . Saved me :) .